# I'm trying to read from a file in C and I have debugged all my errors except for one that I can't figure out

Tags: c, string, ncurses

My buddy and I are working on a simple project, and we decided to go with C this time. We are relatively new to C but wanted to give it a shot anyways. We are trying to read a file and print it to the screen.

Here is our code:

```
//imports libraies
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  //relates to string.h
#include <string.h>  // adds support for string type variables


// Marks anything between the the next curly brackest as the main function
int main() {
  //declaring vars
  FILE* logo; // Makes logo a pointer
  int run;    // sets "run" as a variable, this will be used later in the program to tell the program to move on
  logo = fopen("assets/log.ass", "r");  // Opens the logo file and puts it into ram as "log"
  char line; //Makes variable that will store each line of file read from
  //setting up ncurses
  initscr();  //Creates stdscr *Used by ncurses for keyboard input*
  raw();  //defines ncurses mode, raw should be used for now

  //Displays opening screen and prompts the user to press enter to start the program
  //While using ncurses like we are now use "printw" instead of "printf" to display text
  do { //prints logo to screen 
  line = fgetc(logo); // Saves first line of log in pre-allocated memory
  printw("%c", line); // Prints the var to the screen
} while(logo != EOF);

  getch();  //Waits for user to press any key but soon I will make it "Enter" key specific"

  endwin(); //kills ncurses. If this command is not called the program will not close right, I will put it above return for now 
  return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile and link my code, the compiler says this:

```
Main.c: In function ‘main’:
Main.c:24:14: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
   24 | } while(logo != EOF);
      |              ^~
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccYN1f5L.o: warning: relocation against `stdscr' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccYN1f5L.o: in function `main':
Main.c:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `initscr'
/usr/bin/ld: Main.c:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `raw'
/usr/bin/ld: Main.c:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `printw'
/usr/bin/ld: Main.c:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `stdscr'
/usr/bin/ld: Main.c:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `wgetch'
/usr/bin/ld: Main.c:(.text+0x73): undefined reference to `endwin'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have fixed many syntax errors which has helped, but I can't seem to figure this problem out.

Comment: Typo? You’re comparing your FILE pointer to EOF which is an integer. You should be comparing _line_ not _logo_. Side note fgetc returns an integer, not a char, this will be important when you want to check for EOF. Make sure you link against the curses library as well.

Comment: You need to test the return value from `fgetc()`, not test whether the file stream suddenly equals EOF (it never will).  Use a top-testing loop, too, and save the return value from `fgetc()` in an `int`, not a `char`: `int c; while ((c = fgetc(logo)) != EOF) { … }`.  Note that your variable named `line` is a misnomer; it stores a single character (byte).

Comment: The 'undefined reference' messages are telling you that you didn't add `-lncurses` to the linker command line after the object files.

Answer (score 1):

Your code relies on the file assets/log.ass which you did not supply.  This means I cannot test it but this compiles without warning with `gcc 1.c -lcurses`.  It checks the return value for `fopen()`, and more importantly changes the type of the variable for the return value of `fgetc()` to an `int` and checks it for EOF before use:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *logo = fopen("assets/log.ass", "r");
    if(!logo) {
        printf("failed to open file\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    initscr();
    raw();
    for(;;) {
        int ch = fgetc(logo);
        if(ch == EOF)
            break;
        printw("%c", ch);
    }
    getch();
    endwin();
}
```